# Taxonomy views exposed sort sorting only with all terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ubercart

i am building eshop using ubercart
i am using views3 to show catalog categories (taxonomy terms)

everything works fine, but when i create exposed sort by price field, and use it, it show all terms, so in the url of site is catalog/all (not catalog/3)
i solved it with jquery (form action link replaced)

BUT sorting works only with "all" in site url.(catalog/all?sort_by=sell_price&sort_order=)ASC)
so when i use manually term id it not works (catalog/3?sort_by=sell_price&sort_order=ASC)

has someone knows why?

thank you a lot for you time, guys.
and sorry for my english :D